# Can not get array of Observables

Tags: rxjs

I have a method, that should return an array inside an Observable. I should make some changes to the array and only after that return it. Now I return only one element of type `AlArticleShort`. How can I return an array of type `AlArticleShort[]`?

`Response.shortArticlesInfo` is an array of objects with type `AlArticleShort`. I have to do some actions with that array and return the modified array.

```js
public getArticles(): Observable<AlArticleShort[]> {
  return this.apiBaseService.get<GetArticlesResponse>('getBlogArticles').pipe(
    take(1),
    switchMap(response => {
      return response.shortArticlesInfo;
    }),
    map(article => {
      this.getAllArticlesTags$().subscribe(tags => {
        console.log(tags);
        return article.tags = tags.filter(tag => {
          return article.tagIds.includes(tag.id);
        });
      });
      return []
    }),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using a second pipe by using `map` instead of `mergeMap` or `switchMap`.
In addition, if you want to subscribe to the tags only once you can use `withLatestFrom`.

The final result should look something like:

```
public getArticles(): Observable<AlArticleShort[]> {
    return this.apiBaseService.get<GetArticlesResponse>('getBlockArticles').pipe(
      take(1),
      withLatestFrom(this.getAllArticlesTags$()),
      map(([{ shortArticlesInfo }, tags]) => 
        shortArticlesInfo.map(article => {
           return {
             ...article,
             tags: tags.filter(tag => article.tagIds.includes(tag.id))
           }
        })
      )
    )
 }
```